# Using AWS Appsync with DynamoDB, should you model relationships by storing "redundant copies" of related data on the same table (denormalization)?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, non-relational-database

I was recently reading through [this section in the ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) (or the guide to be more precise). It says that you should try to use a non-relational database the intended way, meaning you should avoid joins between different tables because they are not designed to handle those well. This also reminds me on the section in the DynamoDB docs stating that most well-designed DynamoDB backends only require one table.

Let's take as an example a recipes database where each recipe is using several ingredients. Every ingredient can be used in many different recipes.

**Option 1**: The obvious way to me to model this in AppSync and DynamoDB, would be to start with an `ingredients` table which has one item per ingredient storing all the ingredient data, with the `ingredient id` as partition key. Then I have another `recipes` table with the partion key `recipe id` and an `ingredients` field storing all the `ingredient id`s in an array. In AppSync I could then query a recipe by doing a GetItem request by `recipe id` and then resolving the `ingredients` field with a BatchGetItem on the `ingredients` table. Let's say a recipe contains 10 ingredients on average, so this would mean 11 GetItem requests sent to the DynamoDB tables.

**Option 2:** I would consider this a "join like" operation which is apparently not the ideal way to use non-relational databases. So, alternatively I could do the following: Make "redundant copies" of all the ingredient data on the `recipes` table and not only save the `ingredient id` there, but also all the other data from the `ingredients` table. This could drastically increase disk space usage, but apparently disk space is cheap and the increase in performance by only doing 1 GetItem request (instead of 11) could be worth it. [As discussed later in the ElasticSearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization-concurrency.html) this would also require some extra work to ensure concurrency when ingredient data is updated. So I would probably have to use a DynamoDB stream to update all the data in the `recipes` table as well when an ingredient is updated. This would require an expensive Scan to find all the recipes using the updated ingredient and a BatchWrite to update all these items. (An ingredient update might be rare though, so the increase in read performance might be worth that.)

I would be interested in hearing your thoughts on this:

- Which option would you choose and why?
- The second "more non-relational way" to do this seems painful and I am worried that with more levels/relations appearing (for example if users can create menus out of recipes), the resulting complexity could get out of hand quickly when I have to save "redundant copies" of the same data multiple times. I don't know much about relational databases, but these things seem much simpler there when every data has its unique location and that's it (I guess that's what "normalization" means).
- Is `getRecipe` in the Option 1 really 11 times more expensive (performance and cost wise) than in Option 2? Or do I misunderstand something?
- Would Option 1 be a cheaper operation in a relational database (e.g. MySQL) than in DynamoDB? Even though it's a join if I understand correctly, it's also just 11 ("NoSQL intended way") GetItem operations. Could this still be faster than 1 SQL query?
- If I have a very relational data structure could a non-relational database like DynamoDB be a bad choice? Or is AppSync/GraphQL a way to still make it a viable choice (by allowing Option 1 which is really easy to build)? I read some opinions that constantly working around the missing join capability when querying NoSQL databases and having to do this on the application side is the main reason why it's not a good fit. But AppSync might be a way to solve this problem. Other opinions (including the DynamoDB docs) mention performance issues as the main reason why you should always query just one table.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late, I know, but might help someone down the road.

Start with an entity relationship diagram as this will help determine your options. Even in NoSQL, there are standard ways of modeling relationships.

Next, define your access patterns. Go through all the CRUDL operations and make sure that for each operation, you can access the specific data for that operation. For example, in your option 1 where ingredients are stored in an array in a field: think through an access pattern where you might need to delete an ingredient in a recipe. To do this, you need to know the index of the item in the array. Therefore, you have to obtain the entire array, find the index of the item, and then issue another call to update the array, taking into account possible race conditions.

Doing this in your application, while possible, is not efficient. You can also code this up in your resolver, but attempting to do so using velocity template language is not worth the headache, trust me.

The TL;DR is to model your entire application's entity relationship diagram, and think through all the access patterns. If the relationship is one-to-many, you can either denormalize the data, use a composite sort key, or use secondary indexes. If many-to-many, you start getting into adjacency lists and other advanced strategies. Alex DeBrie has some great resources [here](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE).